# UICollectionView is scrolling after selection

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have got custom `UICollectionView` with 4 items and horizontal scrolling. So 3 items are visiable, and one more is not. After scrolling to the end, I want to select last (4) cell, and after this - my `UICollectionView` view scrolls to the 0.0 `offset`, so there is feeling like cell (4) is not selected, but after rescroll to the end I see that it is selected. My goal is to remove this strange "`autoscroll`" to start. I have got custom layout

```
    let collectionViewLayout = FullyHorizontalFlowLayout()
    collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

    collectionViewLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 60) / 3, (((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 60) / 3 ) + 50));
    collectionViewLayout.nbColumns = 1;
    collectionViewLayout.nbLines = 1;
    collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    collectionViewLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

    collection.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewLayout
    collection.pagingEnabled = true
    collection.scrollsToTop = false


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print(self.bottomCollectionView.contentOffset)

    if collectionView.tag == 1 {
        let indexPath = bottomCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()?.first
        if indexPath != nil {
            bottomCollectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath!, animated: false)
        }
    } else {
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()?.first
        if indexPath != nil {
            self.collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath!, animated: false)
        }
    }
    print(self.bottomCollectionView.contentOffset)
}

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView.tag == 1 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell_for_master_pick", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MasterPickCollectionViewCell
            let service = servicesCategoriesArray[indexPath.item]
            cell.masterPhotoView.layer.cornerRadius = (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 80) / 6
            cell.photoOutsideView.layer.cornerRadius = (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 80) / 6
            print(service.name)
            cell.masterNameLabel.text = service.name
            cell.masterPhotoView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: service.image_url!))

            cell.masterPhotoView.backgroundColor = Colors().gBarVioletColor
//            cell.layoutIfNeeded()

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell_for_master_pick", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MasterPickCollectionViewCell
            let service = packagesArray[indexPath.item]
            cell.masterPhotoView.layer.cornerRadius = (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 80) / 6
            cell.photoOutsideView.layer.cornerRadius = (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 80) / 6
            print(service.name)
            cell.masterNameLabel.text = service.name
            cell.masterPhotoView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: service.image_url!))

            cell.masterPhotoView.backgroundColor = Colors().gBarVioletColor
//            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            return cell
        }
```

Comment: can you share your code for `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` and `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`?

Comment: added. Anyway, I commented didSelect and didDeselect method, and bug appears, so there is no need to try it.

Comment: Also, I have 2 collection views top and bottom one, but this issue doesnt impact on this autoscroll bug too. When I am disabling paging on collection view - all is ok, but I need this functional